# Cocoa iPhone SDK development - touchesBegan method not working if the UIImageView has CABasicAnimation attached

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, touchesbegan, cabasicanimation

I've created a class derived from UIImageView (class name Customer).
Within this Customer class I implemented the method "touchesBegan" .

Also, I applied a CABasicAnimation to the layer of the Customer class .
(the animation simply moves the imageview. it's neccessary because i want to track the animationDidStop event) .

the problem is that the touchesBegan doesn't work when i touch the current position of the imageview. it works only when i touch the original frame (where it was created).

My suggestion is that touchesBegan not applying on the presentationLayer, but on the original frame .

Do you have a way of solving this issue ??
I really would like to solve this from within the Customer class , and not from the main UIViewController .

Thanks a lot,
  Shahar.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled `userInteraction` flag to `YES` for `Customer` class.

Thanks,

Comment: Yes I have. When I clicked on the origin frame's position it does work.
But the frame moves via CABasicAnimation which changes the presentationLayer . I wish to catch the click within the presentationLayer ..